# Porqué la función no reconoce el negativo?

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo aquí una función cuyo propósito es sacar el número de un string para convertirlo en un INT. El problema es que no reconoce el signo negativo a pesar de que el findall lo incluye, dejo abajo el código y un ejemplo del string de donde está sacando el número para que puedan reproducir el problema.

```
def Sacar_peso():
    global datos
    texto="ST,GS,-     36kg"
    def convertir():
        global numero, variable_peso
        numero = [float(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', texto)]
        variable_peso=numero[0]
    convertir()
    print(variable_peso)
    label_peso.configure(text=variable_peso)
```

El texto:**"ST,GS,-     36kg"** es la lectura del indicador de una balanza, necesito que la función registre que está leyendo un número negativo. Gracias

Comment: ¿Te funciona si después de la 3ra línea pones `texto = texto.replace(' ', '')`?

Comment: @aeportugal Si funcionó hermano, muchas gracias ya subo la respuesta. ¿Podrías explicarme que hace el .replace?

Comment: Lo que hace [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) es buscar el caracter del primer argumento, y lo reemplaza por el caracter del segundo argumento. Si solo se usan 2 argumentos, reemplazará todas las ocurrencias. Para este caso, los espacios los reemplazará por *nada*, o sea los eliminará. De usar esta opción, el regex quizás pueda quedar más sencillo: `r'[-]*[\d]+'`

Comment: Gracias, lo tendré en cuenta

Answer (score 0):

@aeportugal me dió la respuesta en los comentarios. Aquí se las dejo

```
def Sacar_peso():
    global datos
    texto="ST,GS,-     36kg"
    texto = texto.replace(' ', '')
    def convertir():
        global numero, variable_peso
        numero = [float(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', texto)]
        variable_peso=numero[0]
    convertir()
    print(variable_peso)
    label_peso.configure(text=variable_peso)
```